# SqlException was unhandled by codeuser

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm building a user registration page that save user's info into a local database. However I get a `SqlException` error. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? I'm developing the program in ASP.net and using the local database server.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisterConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        string checkUser = "select count(*) from Table where userName = '" + txtUN.Text + "'";

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(checkUser, conn);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(comm.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

        if (temp == 1)
        {
            Response.Write("user already exist");
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try 
    { 
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisterConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();

        string insertQuery = "insert into Table(UserName, name, Address, e-Mail, IC, phone, password) values(@Uname, @name, @add, @mail, @ic, @phone, @pswrd) ";

        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Uname", txtUN.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add", txtAdd.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail", txtEmail.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ic", txtIC.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", txtPhone.Text);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pswrd", txtPsswrd.Text);

        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

        Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
        Response.Write("registration was succesful");
        conn.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write("error"+ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is raised the exception? Page_Load or Button_Click?

Comment: In VS you can examine the details of the exception. That may give you a hint of what is going on. If not, copy the exception detail to this post. May help somebody else to come with an answer.

Comment: Please ***DO NOT EVER*** store passwords in **clear text** in your database table! That's just asking to be hacked and exposed....

Answer (score 1):

You don't give the details of the exception, (ie: exception.Message and exception.InnerException.Message) but from your code I think you have the classical `"Syntax Error Near ...."`

This is caused by the presence of a reserved keyword in your query text. This reserved keyword is TABLE. You could fix it enclosing the word in square brackets (or better change the name of the table to somenthing more meaningful)

```
  string checkUser = "select count(*) from [Table] where userName = ...";
```

A part from this, remember to use always parameterized queries also for simple tasks as looking for logins. Last but not least, storing password in clear text inside the database is a big NO-NO from a security standpoint. Everyone, having access to your database using some kind of administrative tool, could look at the passwords of your users, someone could intercept the network traffic between user pc and database server and see the credentials sent by your application. So, please, search for password hashing on this site to find a more secure approach to this problem

Comment: you are correct about the details of my exception. sorry for not explaining more detail. however you solve my problem, thanks Steve

Comment: @jenanI if this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.